# gradle 'at.bxm.svntools' plugin to do 'svn update'

Tags: svn, gradle

Looking for ways to 'update' existing SVN checked out code through gradle build script.

I am using [this plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/at.bxm.svntools)

I only see SvnCheckout but not SvnUpdate in the source code or documentation of [this plugin](https://github.com/martoe/gradle-svntools-plugin/tree/master/src/main/groovy/at/bxm/gradleplugins/svntools).

Is there a way to let this plugin support svn update?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can implement your own `SvnUpdateTask` based on the existing plugin code and send a pull request. There's an example of using the SVNKit to perform an update [in the Grails plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-svn/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/svn/SvnClient.groovy#L197). The entire implementation of the update is just two lines:

```
def updateClient = new SVNUpdateClient(authManager, null)
updateClient.doUpdate(wc.canonicalFile, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNDepth.INFINITY, false, false)
```

where `wc` is a `File` representing the root of the Subversion working copy.